# In MVC 3, I can't get @Html.DisplayFor to render a formatted string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, data-annotations

I'm hoping this is quite a simple one, although after lots of Googling, I've not been able to work it out.

I'm working on a shopping cart site with MVC 3, and using code-first Entity Framework. The model I'm sending over is a list of Product objects, and each of those objects includes this property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field.")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Range(1.00, 500.00, ErrorMessage = "Products can not be free.")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
[DisplayName("Price")]
public double Price { get; set; }
```

I was hoping that the DisplayFormat attribute would cause the following line in the view to format the value as a currency (item is the product object in the loop):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
```

But this doesn't apply the formatting at all. So far the only way I've been able to get it to work is to use this instead:

```
@String.Format("{0:C}", item.Price)
```

But if it's possible, I'd rather use @Html.DisplayFor as it's designed to handle things like nulls. I know it's going to be 0 or more. In fact with the validation it'll always be some amount - but I want to make sure there isn't a more correct way of doing this before I carry on.

Any information on this would be most appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Darin answered and pointed out that it does work, which caused me to go back over what I was actually sending over to the view. I realised that although I have a class called ProductModel, which has the DisplayFormat attribute, I was actually returning another model which contains a list of products. This is called ProductListModel and I realised that it returned a list of the Product data class - not the ProductModel class!

So in the end it was actually very simple. Just wish I hadn't wasted half an evening on it. Thanks for inspiring me to go back and check properly, Darin!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But this doesn't apply the formatting at all.

Oh, you gotta be doing something very wrong as the DisplayFormat attribute should work. For example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Range(1.00, 500.00, ErrorMessage = "Products can not be free.")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    [DisplayName("Price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Price = 0.56
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Price)
```

When I run this application I get, as totally expected, `$0.56`.

So what gives? How does your scenario differs than mine?

Comment: You're right Darin. It was late in the day and I was making the stupid mistake of thinking I was displaying one thing when actually I was displaying another! I'll update my post. Thanks for proving that it does work though!

Comment: just `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` is sufficient.  you don't even need the DisplayFormat

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a `Currency.cshtml` `DisplayTemplate` and remove the `DisplayFormat` attribute.  Then in your `Currency.cshtml` you would format it however you like.

As part of the templating process, `DataType` is used to select a template.

However, as Darin says, this should work without doing this.  Do you, by any chance already have a `Currency.cshtml` file in your `DisplayTemplates` that does not apply formatting?