# what decimal value got rounded in Razor view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My model contains a decimal column, I have checked inside Controller action it has decimal values like below:

```
0.69874
0.78562
```

Strange though, when they appear on web page, they are rounded and they become `0.70`

My model class has this property as:

```
  public virtual decimal Rate { get; set; }
```

Inside view code is:

```
<td>@(Html.DisplayFor(m=>row.Rate))</td>
```

Can you please guide why it is being round automatically and what I should do to stop this, I want to display what ever is real value.

Much thanks for your guidance and helping me.

Comment: The property you listed is virtual -- is it overridden in a derived class, perhaps with a display attribute applied?

Comment: see this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312529/in-mvc-3-i-cant-get-html-displayfor-to-render-a-formatted-string -- Leverage the DisplayFormat attribute on your Model property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Display attribute on the property in question

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F3}")]
public virtual decimal Rate { get; set; }
```

Here are more options for formats
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

Comment: I tried this but got this error:
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions. Any guidance plz

Comment: thanks, it worked. You are a champ. Before closing question can I please ask you 2 things. 
1. Why values are being rounded automatically ?
2. Why I cant use .tostring() inside razor view.

Much appreciate your help.