# Why razor is rounding to a decimal type to 2 decimal places automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, decimal, rounding

This is the field I have in my View Model:

```
public decimal MyValue { get; set; }
```

Here is how I show the value in a View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyValue)
```

I debugged all the way from DB and turned off all JS. I still get that model in View has value 12.34345, but the final value that is presented to a user is 12.34.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416431/what-decimal-value-got-rounded-in-razor-view) question is asking HOW to tackle this but WHY is left unclear.

Interestingly, when I use:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyValue)
```

rounding is not happening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a function of the default `EditorTemplate` for `decimal`. Form the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs) (note the format is `"{0:0.00}"`)

```
internal static string DecimalTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
    if (html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model)
    {
        html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:0.00}", html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
    }
    return StringTemplate(html);
}
```

If you want to display the decimal places as saved, use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyValue)`, or you can apply your own format using the `DisplayFormatAttribute`, which will be respected by the `EditorFor()` method, for example

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`
public decimal MyValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F5}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` is also applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at below source code 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6436538068d19c475d5f7c9ce3d0080d2314f69d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Internal/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs

see below method

```
public static IHtmlContent DecimalTemplate(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == htmlHelper.ViewData.Model)
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue =
                string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:0.00}", htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        }

        return StringTemplate(htmlHelper);
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged for [`asp.net-mvc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) not for [`asp.net-core`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I really don't see any differences out there in both.